A B-movie about soldiers fighting robots
I recently watched the second half of a cheaply made B-movie on tv, it was in English, recent, probably from the last 10 years.
The characters had some strange names, Corina Nadeer & Tolan Van Ray Berg (I searched for those names but nothing came up)
It was about a group of soldiers fighting robots, and defending against the robots attack.
The main character was a male soldiers, his name was Mitchell/Mitch (Not sure but there was definitely a character named Mitchell). He was leading a group of soldiers and they had to retreat to their base, but they left someone behind, Corina . 
He had to tell (another main character), Tolan, that her wife Corina was left behind, she wanted to go to save her, but he convinced her that her place is here (in charge of the base?) and he'll go save her (he loves Corina too).
When searching for a way to defeat the robots, he was confronted by a scientist that he's a robot too and they can upload something into him that will make them defeat the robots, but he'll die, still they can keep a version of him, he refused (keeping a version) saying "I lived as a human and will die as one".
Then, they were attacked by the robots, and kept fighting them, via guns fighting in the ground and via futuristic fighters or small space ships.
He found Corina, still he had to sacrifice himself doing (whatever this thing was) to defeat the robots. They said goodbyes and he told her that he loves her, they kissed, then he "saved the world" and died.
The movie ends with the humans winning the war and Tolan and Corina reuniting.

So, you're actively seeking out an Asylum production? ;) This would be Transmorphers from 2007, so named to cash in on the release of the first Transformers movie. You described it well:

In the year 2009, a race of aliens that pilot robots has conquered the Earth and forced humanity underground and changed the atmosphere to one where it is constantly raining and in darkness. Now in the year 2337, after 300 years of domination, a small group of human rebels plan to take back their world from the mechanical invaders in an ultimate battle, but they soon learn the aliens do not pilot the robots they are the robots a kind of biological-machine hybrid. [...]
the female leader of the human resistance group, General Van Ryberg (Eliza Swenson), quarrels with fellow resistance officers how to fight their war. Van Ryberg decides to seek help by reinstating a disgraced former soldier named Warren Mitchell (Matthew Wolf) [...] Mitchell is happy to be reinstated, but learns that his former one-time love interest, Karina Nadir (Amy Weber), a pilot with the strike squadron, is married to General Van Ryberg. [...]
Mitchell learns a suprising twist from the team's resident scientist Dr. Voloslov Alextzavich (Michael Tower), that Mitchell himself is an android constructed by Dr. Alextzavich whom has human feelings and understandings. Mitchell realizes that he must get the Z-bot's fuel cell to the radio tower to implant it into the tower's computer drive to try to shut down the robots. [...]
Back at the radio station, Mitchell, now aware of his cyborg abilities, sacrifices himself to take out the tower and buy enough time for Itchy and the rest of the group to escape. This stops the reproduction and destroys the station. All over the world, the robots are shut down and defeated. With the battle won, Karina and Van Ryberg are reunited and the surviving humans see the sun shine through the clouds for the first time in centuries.

Here's the trailer:




I guess I'm indeed seeking out an Asylum production! I did know the movie is bad but still couldn't help it. Anyway, thx, Walt, you've been as always a great help.
